# Где в BitBucket находится ссылка на репозиторий

Tags: git, bitbucket

Где в bitbucket можно найти ссылку на репозиторий чтобы сделать синхронизацию с ним? (git remote add origin ...)

Comment: Кнопочка Clone должна быть, если её нет, значит владелец репозитория запретил

Comment: попробуйте поискать в адресной строке браузера. пример: `https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/Tutorial` → `$ git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef`